# How to do conditional scaling in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe and I want to do scaling of a column depending on whether its value is positive or negative, scaled by respective sum (positive or negative) and over another column.

Below is an example for illustration for what I tried.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, 3, -2, -1, 1, 2],
        "bar": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    }
)

foo_is_neg = pl.col("foo") < 0

df.with_column(
    pl.when(foo_is_neg)
    .then(pl.col("foo") / pl.col("foo").filter(foo_is_neg).sum())
    .otherwise(pl.col("foo") / pl.col("foo").filter(~foo_is_neg).sum())
    .over("bar")
    .alias("foo2")
)

df
```

After running through the code above, I got the following output which seems to be what I want.

```
foo bar foo2
--- --- ---
i64 i64 f64
1   1   0.25
3   1   0.75
-2  1   0.666667
-1  1   0.333333
1   2   0.333333
2   2   0.666667
```

But I also got a message along with the output above saying:

```
The predicate '[(col("foo") < (0i64)]' in 'when->then->otherwise' is not a valid aggregation and might produce a different number of rows than the groupby operation would. This behavior is experimental and may be subject to change
```

So, my question is

1. What is this message all about?
2. Is what I did the correct way?
3. I assume there should be a canonical/better way to do it without such warning message. Is it? If so, what should it be like?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not 100% sure what is happening but using `.sum().over("bar")` inside then/otherwise instead of `.otherwise().over()` seems to do it without the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for a "better" approach - you could consider:

```
foo_is_neg = pl.col("foo") < 0
df.with_columns(
   (pl.col("foo") / pl.sum("foo").over([foo_is_neg, "bar"]))
   .alias("foo2")
)
```

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ foo | bar | foo2     │
│ --- | --- | ---      │
│ i64 | i64 | f64      │
╞═════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 1   | 1   | 0.25     │
├─────┼─────┼──────────┤
│ 3   | 1   | 0.75     │
├─────┼─────┼──────────┤
│ -2  | 1   | 0.666667 │
├─────┼─────┼──────────┤
│ -1  | 1   | 0.333333 │
├─────┼─────┼──────────┤
│ 1   | 2   | 0.333333 │
├─────┼─────┼──────────┤
│ 2   | 2   | 0.666667 │
└─────┴─────┴──────────┘
```